# Is there any way to add "<a href=""> on a jquery button to go to a new URL after submitting the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use lots of jquery buttons on my web app to submit the page.  I use them like this:

```
<button type="submit">Save</button>
```

I would love to add a `<a href="">` on a jquery button to go to a new URL after submitting the page.  Like this:

```
<a href="document_view.php?id=123>"><button>View</button></a>
```

In Firefox 3.6.23, this works great.  The browser goes to that URL. 
In IE 8.0.6, this View button will not go that URL, it will only submit the page.

Is there any way I could get this working in IE also?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either submit the form to a specific URL or you go to another URL. You can't do both without ajax or server-side redirection.

- with ajax, the button does not submit a form - you make it submit it via `$.post(url, form.serialize())` for example.
- with server-side redirection you submit the form, and the server-side code sends a redirect (301 or 302) to the page you like. (how exactly to send the redirect depends on the language. It is done by setting the `Location` response header)